# Why is vscode auto-completing import suggestions on left parentheses?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

Seems like an odd "confirmation" trigger, given that I have to type those quite often for unrelated functions, etc.

Comment: since you are not defining a new variable or a function, it thinks you want to use existing functions..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Daniel M mentioned, since I'm referencing a test global vscode isn't aware and tries to guess the function I'm typing.

Solution is to add jest types:

`yarn add --dev @types/jest`

Answer (score 1):

Extensions that provide intellisense can define "commit characters" that accept the current suggestion when typed. VS Code's JS and TS support marks `.` as a commit character for all suggestions, as well as treating `(` as a commit character for function/method suggestions.

To prevent this, either press `esc` to cancel out of the suggestion dialog before typing `(`, or [set](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings):

```
"editor.acceptSuggestionOnCommitCharacter": false
```

to disable commit characters entirely.